# background-image is stretching on both sides not covering the container properly

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am trying to cover a container with an image but for some reason it has not worked, either cover the whole container but looks blurry or it is does not look blurry but stretches on the sides.

I've tried using `background-size: 100% 100%`, `cover`, `contain` and neither of those fixed the issue

Here is the HTML:

```
<section class="image-container">
        <div class="image img-atributes"></div>
    </section>
```

And here is the css:

```
image {
    background-image: url(/ArturoCalle/images/BANNER-HOME-WOMAN-1920.jpg);
background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%; /* I tried cover and contain too */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Do you want it to maintain aspect ratio or stretch to fill the area? Or should it repeat?

Comment: If you want to cover the whole container and the width/height of the `image` container is bigger than the actual image or of different aspect ratio of course it will look blurred and/or stretched.

Comment: background-size: 100% 100% is definitely going to stretch your image on some devices but can you describe what was wrong with cover because that should never stretch/distort an image, only crop it. It might look blurry if the basic image isn't large enough and it has to scale it. Perhaps put a link to your actual image so we can try it.

Comment: ```background-size: cover``` could work maybe

Comment: your image has low resolution

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a fixed(px) height and width for the image instead of percentages.

```
<section class="image-container">
   <div class="image img-atributes"></div>
</section>


.image {
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1625036810640-f06885b8f47d?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw3fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80);
    background-position: center center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/samuvpd/pen/gOWpYPV